# Resetting system index of feature collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, indexing

I am using the sample to repeatedly sample from an image and because I am sampling many times and merging the collections, the ids are coming like 1_1_1_1_1_2_8. I am pretty new to EE so I am not sure if I am doing it the optimal way.

How can I proceed?

```
SAMPLE = ee.FeatureCollection(PSU_CP.iterate(function(cur,coll){  
      img = image.clip(cur.geometry());  
      fc = img.sample({numPixels: sSample , scale: 30, seed:seed_key, geometries:true})  
    return ee.FeatureCollection(coll).merge(fc)  
    }, ee.FeatureCollection([first]) ));
```

Comment: Have you tries adding a property to each feature using set(). Then you can filter on that property later on. Add a link to the script if that won't succeed.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for replying. I am not sure if I get your point. I don't want to filter it later on. Since I using iterate and sampling for every feature, the id ("system:index") being assigned is really weird. On sampling for the first feature, it assigns 1,2,3....,20 . On sampling for 2nd feature, it assigns 1_1, 1_2, 1_3...1_20 . and then 1_1_1, 1_1_2..1_1_20 and so on. So I want it to get ids like 1,2,3...,20,21,22,23.....40,41,42...60. I'll try to post the link here asap. Just wanted to clarify my problem.